# How do I pass a subdirectory path to the GunDB S3 storage driver so the same S3 bucket can be shared with non-Gun data?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, gun, gundb

I see examples referencing a few parameters for the S3 storage driver for [GunDB](http://gun.js.org/) that look like this:

```
var Gun = require('gun');
var gun = Gun({ 
    file: 'data.json',
    s3: {
            key: '', // AWS Access Key
            secret: '', // AWS Secret Token
            bucket: '' // The bucket you want to save into
    }
});
```

I don't see a parameter to define a subdirectory/path within the S3 bucket, to facilitate sharing the bucket with non-GunDB data. Is there such an option/parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hillct there is an option called `prefix`, thank you for pointing out that the options aren't documented. Here is how to use it:

```
var Gun = require('gun');
var gun = Gun({ 
    file: 'data.json',
    s3: {
            key: '', // AWS Access Key
            secret: '', // AWS Secret Token
            bucket: '', // The bucket you want to save into
            prefix: 'gun/'
    }
});
```

And just in case, here are some of the other options:

```
{
  throttle: 15 // Throttle writes to S3 in 15 second intervals, keeps S3 API costs down.
  batch: 10 // Or if there are more than 10 things in queue, don't wait.
}
```